# MERN: Getting 400 error bad request on await fetch using POST

Tags: reactjs, firebase, http-post, http-status-code-400

I'm stuck trying to send some data to Firebase, I'm getting the 400 Error Bad request (it says null). This is the snippet of code:

```
  const submitOrderHandler = async (userData) => {
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    await fetch("https://movieserp-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/orders.json", {
      method: 'POST',
      BODY: JSON.stringify({
        user: userData,
        orderedItems: cartCtx.items,
      }),
    });
    setIsSubmitting(false);
    setDidSubmit(true);
    cartCtx.clearCart();
  };
```

I'm pretty sure userData and cartCtx.items are not null, in fact, I sent the output using console log and the data is exactly what I entered, also I'm sure the firebase database is up, actually I did a GET request and it works.

My question is: what am I missing to get this work?

This is the entire code of the component:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import Modal from "../UI/Modal";
import CartItem from "./CartItem";
import classes from "./Cart.module.css";
import CartContext from "../store/cart-context";
import OrderDetails from "./OrderDetails";

const Cart = (props) => {

  const [isCheckout, setIsCheckout] = useState(false);
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [didSubmit, setDidSubmit] = useState(false);
  const cartCtx = useContext(CartContext);

  const totalAmount = `$${cartCtx.totalAmount.toFixed(2)}`;
  const hasItems = cartCtx.items.length > 0;

  const cartItemRemoveHandler = (id) => {
    cartCtx.removeItem(id);
  };

  const cartItemAddHandler = (item) => {
    cartCtx.addItem({...item, amount: 1});
  };

  const orderHandler = () => {
    setIsCheckout(true);
  };

  const submitOrderHandler = async (userData) => {
    setIsSubmitting(true);
    await fetch("https://movieserp-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/orders.json", {
      method: 'POST',
      BODY: JSON.stringify({
        user: userData,
        orderedItems: cartCtx.items,
      }),
    });
    setIsSubmitting(false);
    setDidSubmit(true);
    cartCtx.clearCart();
  };

  const cartItems = (
    <ul className={classes["cart-items"]}>
      {cartCtx.items.map((item) => (
        <CartItem
          key={item.id}
          name={item.name}
          amount={item.amount}
          price={item.price}
          onRemove={cartItemRemoveHandler.bind(null, item.id)}
          onAdd={cartItemAddHandler.bind(null, item)}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );

  const modalActions = (
    <div className={classes.actions}>
      <button className={classes["button--alt"]} onClick={props.onClose}>
        Close
      </button>
      {hasItems && (
        <button className={classes.button} onClick={orderHandler}>
          Order
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );

  const CartModalContent = (
    <React.Fragment>
      {cartItems}
      <div className={classes.total}>
        <span>Total Amount</span>
        <span>{totalAmount}</span>
      </div>

      {isCheckout && (
        <OrderDetails onConfirm={submitOrderHandler} onCancel={props.onClose} />
      )}
      {!isCheckout && modalActions}
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  const isSubmittingModalContent = <p>Sending order data...</p>;
  /* incluir transaccion para verificar si es exitoso o hubo algun error */

  const didSubmitModalContent = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>Successfully sent the order!</p>
      <div className={classes.actions}>
        <button className={classes.button} onClick={props.onClose}>
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  return (
    <Modal onClose={props.onClose}>
      {!isSubmitting && !didSubmit && CartModalContent}
      {isSubmitting && isSubmittingModalContent}
      {!isSubmitting && didSubmit && didSubmitModalContent}
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `body` (smallcase) instead of `BODY` (uppercase) in the `fetch` call.

Comment: thanks a lot @d.weiss, that did the trick!